# Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, hyper-v

When I try to run any container on Docker on Windows I get the following error.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: container 
70518b4959aca4092b2f65c0881a6c25851789656e3d7ce2610e6322b32aeffe 
encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows 
system call: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3) extra 
info: 

{
    "SystemType": "Container",
    "Name": "70518b4959aca4092b2f65c0881a6c25851789656e3d7ce2610e6322b32aeffe",
    "Owner": "docker",
    "IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot": true,
    "LayerFolderPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\70518b4959aca4092b2f65c0881a6c25851789656e3d7ce2610e6322b32aeffe",
    "Layers": [
{
  "ID": "db3c3c75-2b7c-5d4a-bde3-463ffc817a5b",
  "Path": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\61ad8a0caffe153621375482f419c592edaade796b909edd8a7edda142818414"
},
{
  "ID": "3e2f377e-6c2f-5b95-9e80-fceef67d4b01",
  "Path": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\54a8c9c1afb96bd64a3dd69f0f84aee1eaf18644791cf2812caeab26adf12632"
}
  ],
  "HostName": "70518b4959ac",
  "HvPartition": true,
  "EndpointList": [
     "36bbd687-56fb-4281-a9ee-4f81dcb5a795"
  ],
  "HvRuntime": {
"ImagePath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\61ad8a0caffe153621375482f419c592edaade796b909edd8a7edda142818414\\UtilityVM"
  },
 "AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery": true
}.
```

I believe the error could be related to the underlying hyper-v settings as I received the same error with a brand new vanilla Hyper-V VM set with just a mounted bootable iso disc.

Here is the docker info

```
Version: 17.11.0-ce-rc3-win38 (14052)
Channel: edge 
Sha1: 32de2331204faa0f33731efe56df79e713ee0fba
Started on: 2017/11/15 22:37:53.300
Resources: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
Edition: Enterprise
Id: 1709
Build: 16299
BuildLabName: 16299.15.amd64fre.rs3_release.170928-1534
```

Steps I have tried all resulting in the same:
 1) Install Docker Edge
 2) Uninstall and Reinstall Docker
 3) Uninstall Hyper-V and reinstall
 4) Changing the Hyper-V Storage locations

Comment: Check [this post from docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/windows-build-14342-remove-netnat-the-requested-operation-is-not-supported/12749/3)

Comment: I just tried the steps laid out in that post and still receive the same error.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but have you double-checked that Hyper-V is enabled?

Comment: I have checked. It is enabled.